# Update Values from Sum of Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
@dt TVP_API_DELIVERY_ORDER  READONLY    
    UPDATE  Stkm SET
            Stkm.Itm_Qty_OnHand = CASE 
                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='I' THEN (Itm_Qty_OnHand- (SELECT SUM(T1.OrderQty) FROM @dt T1 WHERE T1.ItemCode=tvp.ItemCode)) 
                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='U' THEN ((Itm_Qty_OnHand+(SELECT SUM(T2.Dod_Qty) FROM DoD T2 WHERE T2.Itm_cd=tvp.ItemCode AND T2.Do_No=@OrderNo AND T2.Do_Year=@Year))-(SELECT SUM(T3.OrderQty) FROM @dt T3 WHERE T3.ItemCode=tvp.ItemCode))
                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='D' THEN (Itm_Qty_OnHand + (SELECT SUM(T4.Dod_Qty) FROM DoD T4 WHERE T4.Itm_cd=tvp.ItemCode AND T4.Do_No=@OrderNo AND T4.Do_Year=@Year))                                          
                                    ELSE 0
                                  END       
    FROM     @dt tvp 
    INNER JOIN Stkm ON tvp.ItemCode=Stkm.Itm_Cd
```

How to simplify the above query? Is there any way to make the execution of this query faster? I'm updating values from Table Value Parameter (TVP) to table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this way this would be helpful to you:
 Also if found any difficulty let me know. 

 @dt TVP_API_DELIVERY_ORDER  READONLY    
                    UPDATE  Stkm SET
                            Stkm.Itm_Qty_OnHand = CASE 
                                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='I' THEN (Itm_Qty_OnHand- TmporderQunatity.orderQuantity) 
                                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='U' THEN ((Itm_Qty_OnHand+TmpDodQunatity.DodQuantity)-TmporderQunatity.orderQuantity)
                                                    WHEN tvp.Flag='D' THEN (Itm_Qty_OnHand + TmpDodQunatity.DodQuantity)                                          
                                                    ELSE 0
                                                  END       
                    FROM     @dt tvp 
                    INNER JOIN Stkm ON tvp.ItemCode=Stkm.Itm_Cd
                    CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT SUM(T1.OrderQty) AS orderQuantity FROM @dt T1 
                        WHERE T1.ItemCode=tvp.ItemCode
                    )AS TmporderQunatity
                    CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT SUM(T2.Dod_Qty) AS DodQuantity FROM @dt T2
                        WHERE T2.ItemCode=tvp.ItemCode AND T2.Do_No=@OrderNo AND T2.Do_Year=@Year
                    )AS TmpDodQunatity
```